# 'Install App' AppStoreView like the Facebook App for iOS has it

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, mobile

I want to know if there is any known possibility to add such an 'AppStoreInstallView' to my App so that I can, without using sharedApplication to open the AppStore, ask my user to Install a new App.
For the people who don't know how this works:

1:You see the 'Ad' and click on the Bottom Install-Now Button (it says 'Jetzt installieren' (this is a german screenshot))

2:A View slides in and it opens the AppStore page of the shown App

3:To install the App you just need to press Install, it is exactly like the native AppStore App, you are asked to enter your Password and then it proceeds to Download the App.

I already tried to do this with a Webview, but it didn't work, it either won't load the Webpage or redirect me (via SharedApplication I suppose) to the native AppStore App.

So does anyone know how to implement such a feature in my own App?

[See here for more Information regarding this Topic](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/mobile-app-ads/)

[image: The proposed App Installation in the Facebook App]

[image: After clicked Install Now (bottom Button) you get redirected to this AppStore within Facebook where you can install Apps directly without using sharedApplication to open the AppStore itself]

Comment: Ps:I dont want to use the Facebook SDK for that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably want to use an `SKStoreProductViewController`.

There's an excellent reference [here](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Making_Store_Purchases_with_the_SKStoreProductViewController_Class), but the essentials I will

From that article, you can use this code:

```
- (IBAction)showStoreView:(id)sender {

        SKStoreProductViewController *storeViewController = 
              [[SKStoreProductViewController alloc] init];

        storeViewController.delegate = self;

        NSDictionary *parameters =
             @{SKStoreProductParameterITunesItemIdentifier: 
                 [NSNumber numberWithInteger:333700869]};

        [storeViewController loadProductWithParameters:parameters 
             completionBlock:^(BOOL result, NSError *error) {
        if (result)
                [self presentViewController:storeViewController
                                   animated:YES
                                 completion:nil];
        }];

}
```

Replacing `[NSNumber numberWithInteger:xxxxxxxxx]` with the product ID of the app or music or book or whatever. The view controller will automatically adjust itself to the kind if product you are trying to sell.